# Yammer - Can export api set query string since Datetime1 until Datetime2?

Tags: yammer

I use "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export?since=xxx&model=xxx" to get export data,but I can only export data since sometime until now,how can I set an endtime?

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way in the export API to set an end time, only the start time. The endpoint is intended to export data into another system. Not to be used for ad-hoc queries.